# Hide order status in the status dropdown on WooCommerce admin orders page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to hide the status `wc-completed` within the dropdown on the WooCommerce admin orders page. Using CSS is not a good option here but I've found no other way.

The only thing would be to use the `wc_order_statuses` to unset this status, but in this case, refunds can't work anymore because `wc-completed` is the default status for refunds.

So maybe there are some people who did this before and can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked the source code and found no hook or filter to perform this. So my solution is a jQuery function:

```
jQuery( "#order_status option[value='wc-completed']" ).remove();
```

You can replace wc-completed with every other status you want to remove from the dropdown. If you want to remove more then one option, you can do this here:

```
jQuery( "#order_status option[value='wc-completed'], #order_status option[value='wc-pending']" ).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it before but I tried again for you. In my case, unsetting wc-completed status is enough to remove this status and manually refunding is also working fine.

Screenshot: [image]

I tried to find any other solution for you (not CSS), but without working on source code (I mean editing original Woocommerce files) I could not do it.

I think you need wc-completed status for refunding because of your payment system. Maybe it will be better if you manipulate source code of it instead of Woocommerce.

Comment: jQuery( "#order_status option[value='wc-completed']" ).remove();